# PostgreSQL replace specific html element

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I´d like to change a HTML snippet stored in database.

Let's assume there is only one table called `table` with columns `id` and `content`. In content column are stored HTML snippets

It has this kind of format

```
<div class="header">etc etc </div>

<div class="content"> content </div>

<div class="footer"> footer </div>
```

(and possibly more complex html structure).

The goal is to **replace the content div** (so div with class content, there is guaranteed that there is just one div with this class identifier) from stored string **with some text**, for example "TEXT" using SQL on PostgreSQL.

So in this case the result would be

```
<div class="header">etc etc </div>

TEXT

<div class="footer"> footer </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `REGEX_REPLACE()` for this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=50c2dda4472802556aaa9662df5a4ba9)

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(html, '<div class="content">.*?</div>', 'MY TEXT')
FROM t
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it seems to work. The additional slash is a mistake, I´ve fixed that. Thanks